# Laravel POST is unable to function

Tags: html, laravel-5

So I am a beginner to Laravel and I was expiremnting with POST and GET. So I attempted to create a simple form in my views directory called form.blade.php:

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>


<body>
    <form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
        <input type="hidden" name="baz" value="boo" />
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>

</body>
```

My routes file was like this:

```
Route::get('post-form', function(){
    return view('form');

});

Route::post('/', function(){
    $data= Request::all();
    var_dump($data);

});
```

As soon as I attempt to submit the form, an error is thrown at me: 
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:

I do not understand why this is happening as my logic seems to be correct to me. Any help and solutions would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan optimize`, `composer dump-autoload` as well as, `php artisan route:clear`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Route::post('/', function(Request $request){
    dd($request);
});
```

Check if it agrees! Because it works on my project.